# SAUCE_CONFIG_PATH is not working for me in testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, saucelabs

I am trying to use testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs.
My tests can successfully connect to SauceLabs and run there, but testcafe creates a unique sauceconnect tunnel, whereas I need to use a shared tunnel. Also, screenResolution is not being picked up from sauceLabsConfig.json file.

I have saucelabs credentials set as environment variables.
I am launching tests using these commands:

```
export SAUCE_JOB="Regression Job" 
export SAUCE_BUILD="Build 1" 
export SAUCE_CONFIG_PATH="./sauceLabsConfig.json" 
testcafe saucelabs:chrome tests/
```

I created a sauce config JSON file:

```
{
    "parentTunnel": "PARENT_TUNNEL",
    "tunnelIdentifier": "qa",
    "screenResolution": "1920x1080"
}
```

Why is my SAUCE_CONFIG_PATH variable not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, not all SauceLabs options are supported for the 'testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs'. For example, the `tunnelIdentifier` option is not supported. I've created an [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs) in the browser provider repository. Track it be informed about the progress.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So, screenResolution is also not supported in the config file, then?
What options are supported? This is not clearly documented in the docs.

Comment: Yes, you can set `screenResolution` only with an environment variable as described at https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs#configuration
As for other options, I did not find detailed docs on this either, so I recommend you create a separate issue in the https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs repository

Answer (score 0):

Note that this issue seems to be fixed, per this pull request:
https://github.com/DevExpress/saucelabs-connector/pull/33

...and integrated in to testcafe 1.14.0:
https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/tree/v1.14.0